# is there any issue when i'm trying to connect database?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are my codes:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '1',
  database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();

data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    veri = rows;
    return veri;
});

console.log(data);
```

when i run this file(index.js) as below

> node index.js

It returns some error and don't show datas.

My mysql datas below:

```
INSERT INTO `deneme` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'yusuf'),
(2, 'ali');
```

What is the problem?

The error is:

```
{ _callback: [Function],
  _ended: false,
  _callSite: '    at Query.Sequence (/home/yusuf/Masaüstü/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:21)\n    at new Query (/home/yusuf/Masaüstü/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:11:12)\n    at Protocol.query (/home/yusuf/Masaüstü/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:41:24)\n    at Connection.query (/home/yusuf/Masaüstü/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:90:25)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yusuf/Masaüstü/node/index.js:10:19)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)\n    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)\n    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)\n    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)',
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM deneme',
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _events: { error: [Function], packet: [Function], end: [Function] } }
```

Comment: It returns "some" error? What does the error say?

Comment: Silly question: port? is it default for the mysql server instance (3306 from memory) and the error message is important

Comment: Are you sure that's an error message? You're logging the query object. What do you get if you put `console.log( veri )` instead of `return veri` in the query function?

Comment: @Juhana yes, when i run console.log(veri) inside of query it returns true datas. then what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is no problem... `data` does not (and is not supposed to) contain the query results. `return veri;` doesn't do anything; it returns from the anonymous function and the return value is discarded. You should handle the results inside that function.

Comment: then how can i use it in outside? is it impossible?

Comment: I have a hunch it's asynchronous so you have to do it the "node" way.

Comment: highly recommend you to read http://www.nodebeginner.org/, it is free and short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tying to do something synchronously instead of asynchronously.

Your problem is here:

```
data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    veri = rows;
    return veri;
});

console.log(data);
```

You're logging data before the callback has been executed. This is why you need to have the code inside its callback, so it says "once you have finished getting the database results, do this".

```
data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    veri = rows;
    console.log(veri); // will be logged once its finished
});
```

You can access the results outside of this function by doing something like this:

```
var results;
data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    veri = rows;
    results = veri;
    someOtherFunction();
});

var someOtherFunction = function(){
  console.log(results);
}
```

You can look at a module called `async` which is good at doing what you're trying to do.

https://github.com/caolan/async

P.S

Welcome to nodejs.